# I installed CUDA10 but Anaconda installs CUDA9. Can I remove the former?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, anaconda, gpu

As a started with GPU programming, CUDA and Python I decided to install the latest version of CUDA (10) in order to experiment with ML.

After spending considerable time installing (huge downloads) I ended up with a version that isn't supporting Tensorflow.

I discovered the `tensorflow-gpu` meta package using Anaconda though! Now unfortunately I have two versions installed and I am not sure how can I uninstall the version 10! Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you installed via `conda install tensorflow-gpu` all dependencies are in the Conda environment (e.g., CUDA dlls are in the `lib` subfolder in the environment), so yes you can safely uninstall CUDA 10.

**Note**: at least on Ubuntu I saw that XLA JIT optimization of code (which is an experimental feature still) requires CUDA to be installed properly in the system (it looks from some binaries in the CUDA install dir and it seems to be hardcoded that way), but for normal TF execution the Conda setup is perfectly fine.